# Ruby Rails Only some parameters are passed to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a single form of user attributes with about 60 fields, displayed separately by means of toggling hidden divs all on one page. When updating someone else' profile, all fields update as expected. When updating the current logged in profile (current_user), only about 40 of the fields update. Here's what I am observing on the update method for the current_user profile:

When setting a breakpoint directly after @user = User.find(params[:id]) and looking at the parameters that got passed, only about 40 out of the 60 form field parameters are even present. The ones that are present update as expected, and obviously the ones that aren't present don't update.

Any clues as to what might be causing this strange behavior?

**Example: one of many mis-behaving form fields on users/_form.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :street_address, :placeholder => 'address..'  %>
```

**Update Method in users_controller.rb**

```
# UPDATE
  def update   
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    breakpoint_set = on_this_line
    respond_to do |format|     
      if @user.update_attributes params[:user]
        format.html do
          redirect_to("/users", :notice => 'User Profile was successfully updated.')
          format.xml  { head :ok }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: is that a type in your example code? <%= @.text_field...?

Comment: That was a typo, I changed it to f. But unfortunately, this isn't the problem.

Comment: Other things I have tried to no avail are the use of attr_accessible  on all fields and restarting the server. I'm sort of out of ideas.

Comment: Does the result stay the same every time you do this? That is, attributes that got updated correctly would not get updated next time? I want to see if the behavior is consistent.

Comment: Yes, all misbehaving fields are consistent, same ones, every time. The ones that work, always work.

Comment: Then something is not set up correctly. Can you please post your view code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10908/discussion-between-yosep-kim-and-iamtoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the parameters are porting to the controller from client side. You may check this will Firefox + Firebug console.

And check if every parameter is under the user hash, because the missing parameters might not coming in the same user hash (which the Rails controller is looking at).

Comment: Pointing me in this direction led to the resolve. What had happened was a nested form by means of rendering a partial as in <%= render :partial => 'users/address' %> inside of the users form. Even though this form needs to be a form as it is used elsewhere, it wasn't appropriate that I rendered in where I did.

Answer (score 2):

If the "currently logged in user" is just a `User` object, then I suspect you are seeing the side effects of caching.

If you have two Active Record objects that represent the same record, and they disagree about what the state of that record should be, different kinds of problems can happen.  For example;

```
@u1 = User.find logged_in_user_id
@u2 = User.find logged_in_user_id

@u1.update_attributes :username => "root"

@u2.username   # old username
@u2.reload
@u2.username   # "root"
```

Make sure this isn't happening to you.

Comment: As it turns out, this wasn't the issue, but you bring up an interesting scenario I had never thought of. Bringing this scenario to light is particularly interesting in light of some of my code as I may run into this. Thanks for this!